# Java 2D rotation

Tags: java, rotation

Hey guy's im making a 2D java game and i want to learn how to rotate a simple 2D sprite.

Currently my Player class has a rotation integer which decreases/increases on button press. How would i go about rotating my Player image?

This is how I am loading my sprite:

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("player.png");
sprite = i.getImage();
```

This is currently how i draw it:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(),null);
    print("Painting");
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is AffineTransform,

below link will help you to get started

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Good luck!

Comment: Extra hint: in order to use AffineTransform, cast your Graphics object to Graphics2D. It should be safe to do so. This will provide you with a great deal more methods for graphics processing. Also, ImageIcon might not be the best way to obtain an image for this kind of use. Check package javax.imageio for usable stuff.